# How to change Toolbar Text Color in Pre-Lollipop versions

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-toolbar

In Lollipop version, my Toolbar Text color is WHITE, but when i run my app on pre-lollipop devices then showing BLACK instead of WHITE color ...

**styles.xml:-**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>

    </style>
```

**toolbar:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following

toolbarView.setTitleTextColor (toolbarTextColor);

Comment: I don't want to do this programmatically

Comment: Add these two line to your toolbar
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"

Answer (score 1):

You can change your Theme `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` to `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/primary_light</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/primary_dark</item>
    </style>
```

or 
add the item in your `AppTheme`

```
<item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the title textColor of the `Toolbar` via `android:textColorPrimary`.

**Example**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <!-- Used for the title -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffeb3b</item>
    <!-- Used for the menu and back-arrow - can be overriden by colorControlNormal -->
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#03a9f4</item>
</style>
```